# Entity class must be annotated with @Entity

Tags: android, android-room

I'm having issues creating `@Relation`.  I previously was using a complicated query to handle M:N, but I wanted to try the simpler `@Relation` and rely on ids.  However, I get an error whenever I extend or embed the `@Relation` class.  This works:

```
@Entity(tableName = "meta",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = FolderEntity::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"],
    childColumns = ["parentId"],
    onDelete = CASCADE)],
indices = [
    Index(value = ["uri"], unique = true),
    Index(value = ["documentId"], unique = true),
    Index(value = ["parentId"])])
open class MetadataEntity {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
    ...
}

@TypeConverters(MetadataResult::class)
class MetadataResult : MetadataEntity() {
   var keywords: List<String>? = null
   var parentUri: String? = null

   @TypeConverter
   fun fromGroupConcat(keywords: String?): List<String>? = keywords?.split(",")
}
```

However, this does not work:

```
data class MetadataXmp(
   @Embedded
   val metadata:MetadataEntity,
   @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "metaId",
        projection = ["subjectId"],
        entity = SubjectJunction::class)
   var subjectIds: List<Long> = Collections.emptyList(),

   @Relation(
        parentColumn = "parentId",
        entityColumn = "id",
        projection = ["documentUri"],
        entity = FolderEntity::class)
   var parentUris: List<String> = Collections.emptyList())
```

Please note that the varying object type (`class`, `data class`, etc) is just the state of disarray of my attempts.  I have tried various versions of extension with `MetadataXmp` or embedding, abstract, data class, etc.  I don't seem to be able to introduce `@Relation`.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar Error message, for me the issue was that I had not declared the enity in the Database class but I had Annotated the pojo, Posting answer as it might help somebody with similar problem.

Comment: saved me bro, thanks lots. I had encluded the wrong entity class on the entities array

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually related to @RawQuery:observedEntities.  I was observing the result POJO instead of the underlying @Entity.  The error message simply points to the POJO which is misleading.  Google is looking at improving the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while implementing the room DB in our application. but in my case room DB version is 2.2.6 when I increase to the latest version 2.3.0 solved my issue.